# How to access only one class from different module in multi-module spring boot application gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, integration-testing, multi-module

I have 2 modules (Module A and Module B) in my multi-module spring boot application, build using gradle.

Now the `Main` class for spring boot module is present in Module A.
Now I want to access this `Main` class in Module B.

In Module B, I want to write integration test cases and over a Test case class, I want to mention `Main` class in SpringBootTest annotation. Something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class,
webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class TestController {

}
```

But here I am unable to find the `Main` class. What changes should I need to make in gradle file for Module B to support this?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to split your project into modules.
Your settings.gradle and build.gradle should look something like this:

settings.gradle

```
include 'moduleA'
include 'moduleB'
```

moduleB/build.gradle

```
dependencies{
  implementation project(':moduleA')
}
```

More info: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

If you really want to only have the class as the source file, then this should work:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'path/to/the/class'
        }
    }
}
```